# Mysql Stored Procedure - Return Table headers if no Data found

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, magento-1.9

We are using magento and PHP. And have a stored Procedure which do some processing and its finally suppose to return multiple results set using select queries.

```
Eg : Select * FROM table1;
     Select * FROM table2;
     Select * FROM table3;
```

The issue is that, not all tables might have data in it. If there is no data in table stored procedure returns nothing. And in the PHP we are using a for loop to fetch data.

```
for($i= 0; $i<=3; $i++){
        $rowset = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($rowset) {
          switch ($i) {
            case 0:
              $spStatus = $rowset;
              break;
            case 1:
              $boqSections = $rowset;
              break;
            case 2:
              $boqEntries = $rowset;
              break;
            case 3:
              $boqItems = $rowset;
              break;
          }
        }
        $sql->nextRowset();
    }
```

So if there is no data found in table3. Stored procedure will not return a 3rd rowset/resultset. So in the above loop a 3rd call to `$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` will fail causing a General error.

Are there any work around to solve this issue?

Comment: Does each query rely on something from the previous query? What fields does each table involved have and what's the required result at the end of it all?

Comment: Yes each query depends on previous one. 3rd table is child of 2nd table and 2nd table is the child of 1st table. But child tables may or may not have data it depends. However if there is an entry in the 3rd table then there will be definitely a corresponding entry in table2. Same goes with data in table2. We just want to make sure that we there is no data in table3 either mysql should return an empty table with headers or PHP should handle it gracefully

Comment: *"If there is no data in table stored procedure returns nothing."*  That should not be true.  I have code that uses a stored procedure to return multiple result-sets, and their ordinal positions are important.  Empty result sets are returned with the column headers.

Answer (score 0):

Add below condition for rowCount

```
   for($i= 0; $i<=3; $i++){
    $rowset = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    if ($rowset && $sql->rowCount() >0) {
       switch ($i) {
        case 0:
          $spStatus = $rowset;
          break;
        case 1:
          $boqSections = $rowset;
          break;
        case 2:
          $boqEntries = $rowset;
          break;
        case 3:
          $boqItems = $rowset;
          break;
      }
     } else {
       $spStatus = [];
       $boqSections = [];
       $boqEntries = [];
       $boqItems = [];
     }

     $sql->nextRowset();
   }
```

Hope This will help.